# div not inserting correctly problem jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I seem to be having a problem inserting a `<div>` element in the correct area. I want to push a button, in this case "more info" and display more information under the first `div` area using jquery.

example:

```
<div id="Main-info">
     <div id="more-info">

     </div> 
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is the "Main-info" area is calling a php script and grabbing info from the database and displaying it in a table. The second php file I have loads in the "more-info" `div` so when I push the more info button the second php files goes under the entire first `div` but i want it to go under the specific information that I click.

A better example of what I am trying to accomplish is like the [wefollow.com](http://wefollow.com) site, where you push the more info button and more info display right under the info you click. In my case the additional info goes under the entire table at the buttom.

Here is the code:

#### index.php:

```
<?php
include("buy.functions.php");
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="listing.js"></script>

    <div id="article-area">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div id="output-listings">
            <div id="more-information">

            </div>
    <?php outputListingsTable(); ?>

    </div><!--end output-listings-->
```

#### buy.functions.php:

```
<?php
function outputListingsTable()
{
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ajax_demo') or die('you\'re dead');
    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM explore") or die($mysql->error);

    if($result) 
    {
        echo "<table> \n";

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
        {
            $id = $row->id;
            $siteName = $row->site_name;
            $siteDescription = $row->site_description;
            $siteURL = $row->site_url;
            $sitePrice = $row->site_price;

            echo "<div id=\"" . $id . "\"> \n";
            echo "  <tr> \n";
            echo "      <td>" . $siteName . "</td> \n";
            echo "      <td>" . $siteURL . "</td> \n";
            echo "      <td><a id=\"" . $id . "\" class=\"more-info\" href=\"#\">More info</a></td> \n";            
            echo "  </tr> \n";
            echo "</div> \n";           
        }

echo "</table> \n";
    }

}

?>
```

#### getinfo.php:

```
<?php
function outputDescriptionTable($id)
{
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ajax_demo') or die('you\'re dead');   
    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM explore WHERE id=" . $id) or die($mysql->error);

    if($result) 
    {
        echo "<table> \n";

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
        {
            $siteName = $row->site_name;
            $siteDescription = $row->site_description;
            $siteURL = $row->site_url;
            $sitePrice = $row->site_price;

            echo "<div id=\"more-information\"> \n";
            echo "  <tr> \n";
            echo "      <td>" . $siteDescription . "</td> \n";
            echo "      <td>" . $sitePrice . "</td> \n";
            echo "  </tr> \n";
            echo "</div> \n";           
        }

echo "</table> \n";
    }

}
?>
    <?php $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
    <?php outputDescriptionTable("$id"); ?>
```

#### listing.js:

```
$(function(){
$("tr").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});

$('.more-info').click(function() {
$('#more-information').show().load('getinfo.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id'));
return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) should solve your problem. Something like:

```
$('.more-info').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.more-information').show().load('getinfo.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
});
```

From the doc:

> Closest works by first looking at the
> current element to see if it matches
> the specified expression, if so it
> just returns the element itself. If it
> doesn't match then it will continue to
> traverse up the document, parent by
> parent, until an element is found that
> matches the specified expression. If
> no matching element is found then none
> will be returned.

Also, your 'more-information' divs should have the *class* more-information, as opposed to the ID, as IDs should be unique, else strange things might happen.

Comment: I tried the above script and changed 'more-information' divs to classes, but when I click the 'more-info' button nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @John - sorry, I forgot to mention, closest() needs jQuery 1.3 and above to work. Are you using that?

Comment: @John - Looking into it (sorry, really thought that might have solved it) will get back to you shortly.

Comment: after some messing around and additional divs etc. When clicking on the 'More-info" button nothing still occurs however firebug displays it in the console response using the closest script.